Using prop_search on node groups list changes order of list
I'm developing an addon which performs operations on Geometry Nodes node groups and I noticed that when I use prop_search on the node group list, the one that I select is moved to the top of the list, which is not in alphabetical order anymore. However this only happens in Blender's original UI and not in the custom UI generated with prop_search.

My questions are:
1 - Is it possible to select a node group to perform operations on without altering the order of the list? I tried using EnumProperty instead of prop_search but it doesn't allow searching the list.
2 - Alternatively, is it possible to sort the list back to alphabetical order so that it is displayed correctly in the original Blender UI?
Code:
import bpy

from bpy.types import (PropertyGroup, Panel, Scene)
from bpy.props import (PointerProperty, StringProperty)

class MAIN_PT_panel(Panel): 
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "GN Tools"
    bl_idname = "MAIN_PT_panel"
    bl_label = "GN tools demo"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.my_addon_props
        box = layout.box()

        box.label(text="GN group")
        box.prop_search(props, "selected_group_find", bpy.data, "node_groups", text="Group")

class MYADDON_PG_properties(PropertyGroup):
    
    selected_group_find: StringProperty             (name="Selected Group", default="")  
                                                     
classes = (
    MAIN_PT_panel,
    MYADDON_PG_properties )

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    Scene.my_addon_props = PointerProperty          (type=MYADDON_PG_properties)
def unregister():
    del Scene.my_addon_props
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


prop_search does not seem to have a sorting feature.

@XY The UI created with prop_search actually displays the node groups list correctly in alphabetical order, however the original Blender UI displays it with the latest selected group on the top of the list. I updated the question to make it clearer.

In blender 4.2. I noticed that bpy.data.node_groups will sort the order after renaming node groups. So, the image you provided on the right will never happen.

@XY I tested this with 4.2 but I get the same result. If I select a node group with the prop_search in the addon panel the group is always moved to the top of the list. Then if I rename it, the group (but only the renamed group) goes back to alphabetical order. However if I change it back to the original name it is moved to the top of the list again. You can test this using the code above.

Not sure if it can be sorted. Maybe try to creating a Collection property
